# Cross Compiling with cmake using additional third party libraries

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile my C++ application for ARM with cmake. Therefore I installed the arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ package on my ubuntu x86 system. However, this package does not contain all needed third party libraries for successful linking my C++ application. Example:

**Ubuntu x86 system:**
Contains basic stuff such as

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/libgcc.a
...
```

**Target system (ARM):**
Has further arm-specific packages installed which are needed if I would compile my application directly on the ARM-system. Therefore more libraries are available:

```
/usr/lib/libpq.so
/usr/lib/libpq.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libkrb5.so.3
```

Since the additional libraries are needed for cross compiling my attempt was to copy the required third party libraries manually from the target system to the x86 system. However, this ended up in a desaster since linking turns up messages such as "libssl.so -> requires lib B -> requires lib C which is missing".

**How can I make these libraries available on my x86-system for cross compiling?**

Comment: You may pass options to the linker from `g++` with `-Wl`.  See the command [`-rpath-link`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) in the GNU ld manual.  Put it together as `-Wl,-rpath-link,<ARM path>/lib:<ARM path>/usr/lib`; you may need quoting, depending on how you run it.  Similarily, use `-rpath` to set the run time of where you would like to search on the ARM target.